# Filtering Month in CSV using Bash

Tags: bash, shell, csv, filter

Hey guys I have been working on this problem where I have got a **CSV File** where I have to filter specific months based on the input from the user.
**Record Format**

```
firstName,lastName,YYYYMMDD
```

But the thing is the input is in String and the month in the file is in numbers.

For example

```
> cat guest.csv

Micheal,Scofield,20000312
Lincon,Burrows,19981009
Sara,Tancredi,20040923
Walter,White,20051024
Barney,Stinson,20041230
Ted,Mosbey,20031126
Eric,Forman,20070430
Jake,Peralta,20030808
Amy,Santiago,19990405
Colt,Bennett,19990906

> ./list.sh March guest.csv
Micheal,Scofield,20000312
```

Answer (score 0):

Oneliner:

```
MONTH=March; REGEX=`date -d "1 ${MONTH} 2022" +%m..$`; grep $REGEX guest.csv
```

Comment: This might work in OP case but you should specify that it's for GNU `date` and a CSV with UNIX line endings

Answer (score 0):

Awk can easily translate month names to numbers *and* do the filtering.

```
awk -v month="March" -F , '
    BEGIN { split("January February March April May June July August September October November December", mon, " ");
        for(i=1; i<=12; i++) mm[i] = mon[i] }
    mm[0 + substr($3, 5, 2)] == month' guest.csv
```

The `BEGIN` block sets up a pair of associative arrays which can be used in the main script to look up a month number by name. Change `-v month="April"` to search for a different month.

If you want to wrap this in a shell script, you can easily parse out the arguments into variables:

```
#!/bin/sh
monthname=$1
shift
awk -v month="$monthname" -F , '
    BEGIN { split("January February March April May June July August September October November December", mon, " ");
        for(i=1; i<=12; i++) mm[i] = mon[i] }
    mm[0 + substr($3, 5, 2)] == month' "$@"
```